# Obtener valor de un Json en node.js

Tags: json, nodejs, post

me encuentro estancado y espero me puedas ayudar.
Tengo una API donde hago mis peticiones (Post, Get, Delete, etc.)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta función hago un post enviando un json, la respuesta es otro json, como se ve a continuación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con eso todo va bien, sin embargo no tengo la mas mínima idea de como capturar un valor en específico del json devuelto, en las imágenes anteriores intento capturar el iva, pero de las dos formas que lo intento hacer ( `body.iva`, `body[0]['iva']` ) me salen indefinidas, obviamente están mal formuladas las capturas, y es en ese punto que quisera que me guiaran

Comment: Bienvenido Luis de preferencia el código sea texto es mas fácil para hacer pruebas

Comment: como obtienes el json que envias desde el código de la primera imagen, en el servicio que lo recibe?

Comment: @LeonardJusaOckonell asi es, hago un POST a la URL que esta en la imagen y el me devuelve el JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo compañero que lo que falta es volver al string entrante en un json. puedes intentar esto

```
var myJson = JSON.parse(body);
console.log("mi variable: "+myJson["iva"]);
```

saludos y buena energia :)

Comment: era eso, la respuesta era un texto, no un json :( te lo agradezco

Comment: para servirte :) te invito a marcarla como solución por si alguien tiene el mismo inconveniente, saludos!  me alegra poder ayudarte.

Comment: como obtienes el json que envias desde el código de la primera imagen, en el servicio o el js que lo recibe?